# TestNG run once before running all test suites mentioned in the pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, testng, testng.xml

I have set up multiple testng.xml files in the Surefire plugin so that I can [run the automation test from command prompt using Maven](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/maven-tutorials/choose-selected-testng-xml-files-to-execute-using-maven).

Now, I am facing a problem. How I set up the `suiteListener` to perform a few tasks like delete the files and screenshots that was captured from the previous run. (A single run consists of multiple suite files)

Now what is happening is that the 1st test suite runs and captures the screenshots and creates logs. When the 2nd suite is run, it clears the screenshots and logs that was captured earlier and creates a new screenshots for this run.

Is there a way that we can have this method run once **for each run** and **not before every test suite**.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteListener;
import com.company.appium.base.BaseTest;
public class suiteListener extends BaseTest implements ISuiteListener {

    @Override
    public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
        // This method will be executed before Test Suite run
        try {
            deletePreviousScreenShots();
            System.out.println("Inside onStart of suiteListener");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Before starting test suite: " + suite.getName() + " in onStart() method");
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {
        // This method will be executed at the end of the Test Suite run
        System.out.println("After executing the test suite: " + suite.getName() + " in onFinish() method");
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you have 5 suite files, Are you saying that the above code needs to be run only once after all the 5 suites are completed ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Basically what I am trying to do is clear the screen shots and test reports from the previous run. This is so that I dont have a build up of files from all the previous runs. The code that I have now works when I have only one test suite in surefire plugin. 

When I have lets say 5 test suites, this onstart method is called in the beginning of every suite and clearing the files created by the previous test suite.

I want all the files to be available for each run and then when I re-run the file from the previous run is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Since I am not sure if a new instance of `suiteListener` is created for each suite run. So what you could do is to proceed with the deletion only if the name of the suite received via `ISuite suite` parameter matches with the "first" xml suite file you have provided.

```java
public class suiteListener extends BaseTest implements ISuiteListener {

    private static final String firstTest = "suite1";
    @Override
    public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
        if(!suite.getName().equals(firstTest)) {
            return;
        }

        // rest of the code
    }
}
```